# Controller not found error in laravel . Why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following controller in my laravel application:

```
<?php

namespace Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\PrepareNoticeRequest;
use App\Provider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NoticesController extends Controller {

    public function create() {
        $providers = Provider::lists('name' , 'id');
        return view('notices.create' , compact('providers'));
    }

}
```

And the following route set in the routes.php file:

```
Route::get('notices/create' , 'NoticesController@create');
```

Now when i hit the following URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/laravelApp/public/notices/create
```

I get the following error on my screen:

[image]

Why am i getting a controller not found error when i already have a controller ??

Comment: Your `NoticeController` extends a `Controller` that's the one laravel can't find, you have to include it in your use statements.

Comment: Did you try `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using wrong namespace:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Also, you missed this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

You should use `php artisan make:controller SomeController` command to create controllers if you want to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: The latter isn't necessary as you are already in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace

Comment: @Neat you're right, but it's standard line for Laravel controllers which is created by `php artisan make:controller`. The thing is some controllers will have different namespace, for example `App\Http\Controllers\Admin`, so it's a good idea to keep this line in every controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your namespace value to this :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

And add the following line :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The latter isn't necessary as you are already in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace :)